# Approach for "bookmark" layout

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I am not pretty sure if in web development this kind of thing is called as a 'bookmark' layout. I'll explain on below screen.
[image]

I would like to achieve something like this and missing a knowledge of how to do that. Could someone point me where should I anchore ? I could not find anything in web / probably looking with using bad phrases.

This component would be part of the application, after we push to the router path it's going to display this kind of layout. Basically I could achieve this buy keep pushing a different route for each page, but what if those pages belongs to "one model comoponent" I wouldn't like to reload them all of the time while switching them, just once after we entry to each. It would work like a tab bar in mobile apps (iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many UI contexts (e.g. browsers, macOS applications, etc.) and in Web Development, what you refer to as "bookmark layout" is simply called [**tabs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(GUI)) (like the iOS tab bar that you also mention).

> *I wouldn't like to reload them all of the time while switching them*

Vue offers you the built-in component [`<keep-alive>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) for such use case:

> When wrapped around a dynamic component, `<keep-alive>` caches the inactive component instances without destroying them.

See the Vue guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

> When switching between these components though, you’ll sometimes want to maintain their state or avoid re-rendering for performance reasons. […]
>
> To solve this problem, we can wrap our dynamic component with a `<keep-alive>` element

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this!